# BroadcastEvent is undefined in jitsi android sdk sample

Tags: android, jitsi, jitsi-meet, lib-jitsi-meet

According to [this link](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-android-sdk), I am using jitsi Android SDK

BroadcastEvent is undefined in jitsi Android SDK sample

Comment: Ever find a solution?

Comment: @spartygw Yes,  update version to 3.5.0. Lack of documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update version to 3.5.0

It is a Lack of documentation

Also, see [my sample](https://github.com/HosseinKurd/Jitsi-Meetig-Sample)

Comment: That is my pleasure